# how to delete the data from table for each scheme for fincode

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have table

```
|Schemecode  | Fincode |Invdate     |
|:-----------|--------:|:----------:|
|1           |    81   |  2019-03-31|
|1           |    81   |  2019-04-30|
|1           |    82   |  2019-04-30|
|4           |    34   |  2019-04-30|
|4           |    35   |  2019-04-30|
|6           |    38   |  2019-04-30|
|6           |    38   |  2019-03-31|
|6           |    81   |  2019-04-30|
|6           |    81   |  2019-03-31|
|6           |    42   |  2019-04-30|
```

i want to delete 
all the duplicate rows having Fincode as duplicate for each Schemecode with Invdate older date i.e (2019-03-31)  Not with 2019-04-30.

i have tried query but unable to do

Expected output :

after delete

```
|Schemecode  | Fincode |Invdate     |
|:-----------|--------:|:----------:|
|1           |    81   |  2019-04-30|
|1           |    82   |  2019-04-30|
|4           |    34   |  2019-04-30|
|4           |    35   |  2019-04-30|
|6           |    38   |  2019-04-30|
|6           |    81   |  2019-04-30|
|6           |    42   |  2019-04-30|
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried? Curious to see.

Comment: Of the data you presented in your question what would be the output?

Comment: i have used this , but this is for select query before delete:

SELECT Schemecode,Invdate,Fincode FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(Fincode), Schemecode,Invdate  FROM mf_portfolio ORDER BY Invdate ASC  ) AS inttable GROUP BY Fincode   HAVING COUNT(Fincode) >1

Comment: Fincode should be unique for each schemecode and the row which will be deleted will be older date

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fincode ORDER BY invdate) rn FROM yourtable
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL does not support this syntax so the upvotes are baffling.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are indeed correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a6ea70507418f6f5c81bf27f639cf86

Answer (score 1):

I would write the `delete` as:

```
delete t
from <table> t join
     (select schemacode, fincode, max(invdate) as max_invdate
      from <table> t2
      group by schemacode, fincode
     ) tt
     on t.schemacode = tt.schemacode and
        t.fincode = tt.fincode and
        t.invdate < tt.max_invdate;
```

Comment: i have not tried others answers, but i found this useful . thanks @gordon